# Have child change parent's state which is an array

Tags: reactjs

I know how to have a child control the parent's state by passing down a function, what I have is a parent with a state equal to:

```
ingredients: props.recipe ? props.recipe.ingredients : []
```

It is being passed data from the database which it will populate if it exists and create a new array if not found.  I then have a section where each of the children of the ingredients array gets mapped:

```
this.state.ingredients.map((ingredient) => (
                    <IngredientListItem
                        key={ingredient}
                        name={ingredient}
                        handleRemoveIngredient={this.handleRemoveIngredient}
                    />
                )
```

Inside the IngredientListItem I set a new state to the this.props.name so that I can manipulate it further if the user made a typo when creating that specific ingredient.  Doing this I can freely edit the child's version of what the ingredient is but I can't figure out what I would need to do to pass the new ingredient value back up to the parent so that it could write the new value to the database.

The problem I am having is stemming from editing the values of the array within a state.  Would it be using something like: ///const index = indexOf("example ingredient")/// to get where the old ingredient is then updating it from there?  I know that the state is immutable but I am also not 100% how to use shouldComponentUpdate (which I believe may be able to help me).  Thank in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Please add some code with dummy's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a way for the parent component to identify which child in the list makes the request to handle updated data. The answer is actually simple: pass the index along with whatever parameters the parent requires to complete the update.

```
this.state.ingredients.map((ingredient, index) => (
                    <IngredientListItem
                        key={index}
                        name={ingredient}
                        handleRemoveIngredient={(...args) => { this.handleRemoveIngredient(...args, index) }}
                    />
                )
```

P.S. Using `ingredient` as key is not acceptable if there are two ingredient with same value in array. If that is not the case then it's fine.

Comment: Thank for the response, I'll play around with it when I get a chance.  Also about the key, I have it set so the same ingredient cannot be added so there would never be a duplicate key.  I like your way of using the index though.